# xcode , xml parser

Tags: xml, xcode

Can any buddy have any project in which there is an twitter login form, when the user login, it will whow all the tweets in a tableview and when I click on that cell it will show me description, and when I want to see my twic pic images then it also show me that..

if any buddy have any xcode project (in which it uses the xml parser) then plz give me the tutorial link , so that I can WOrk on it..

Thnx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use TBXML it is easy to understand

Answer (score 3):

Go to sleep, and when you wake up, the code will be in your favorite work folder :) And do you want something for the desert, sir?

Comment: -1 this is no answer but a comment, +2 for being so right in what u say.

Comment: Sorry if being funny, but The stack overflow is supposed to help you about a **specific** programming problem.